# Oracle SQL Delete Operation Performance

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have two tables tableA(33M records) and tableB (270K records),
I want to delete all records in tableA which also exist in tableB. So write a SQL statement below.
I think It should be modified since it table more than 1 hour to remove them all.
Do you have an idea if it is usual for these kind of operation.
Note: primary key of both tables is id.

```
delete from tableA where id in (select id from tableB);
```

Here is the sql statement explain

```
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT        |                        |   289K|  7341K|       | 85624   (1)| 00:17:08 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|   1 |  DELETE                 | tableA |       |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN            |                        |   289K|  7341K|       | 85624   (1)| 00:17:08 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN      | SYS_C0015397           |    36M|   455M|       | 84050   (1)| 00:16:49 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|*  4 |    SORT JOIN            |                        |   289K|  3670K|    11M|  1574   (1)| 00:00:19 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|   5 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| SYS_C0015401           |   289K|  3670K|       |   193   (2)| 00:00:03 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please post the results of "explain plan for <your delete statement" and "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)"

Comment: updated questions adding explain result of sql statement.

Comment: Read this: [Exists x IN Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074)

Comment: I see the row estimate of 999 is incorrect -- should be around 270k. Analyse tableb and try again -- a hash join might be produced, and that might be better.

Comment: Does it help when you calculate statistics of tables: `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('tableA')` and  `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('tableB')`

Comment: I have create a new table having 999 data for testing purpose, otherwise I have to wait so much each time.

Comment: The explain plan needs to be run for the real tables, not the test tables.  `explain plan` should be very quick for any type of query, regardless of the table sizes, with a few rare exceptions.

Comment: @David  you are right, explain result changes per size of data. So I have updated the question adding original query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting execution plan. You don't see merge joins often because they usually require a sort of the data first, but in this case only one data set needs to be sorted because it's accessed via an index fast full scan (which returns unsorted data) instead of an index full scan.

Most of the cost is associated with reading the SYS_C0015397 index via an index full scan, and I'd guess that the optimiser has done the arithmetic for a pair of fast full scans and a hash join and rejected it. Still, I'd see if that can be hinted with:

```
delete /*+ no_use_merge(tablea) */ from ...
```

I'm not sure if that's enough to get a hash join, but see if the explain plan tries something other than a merge join there.

Is the join column on tablea a unique or PK?

Answer (score 0):

Use exists or insert saved data into new table (B), drop old table (A) and rename the new table(B) as a table(A).